# How does one use a CPP program to insert text into a window?

Tags: c++, windows, text

Twice a week I run the same ~50 commands in a program. For example, I type "unix" (then hit enter) to put the program into unix mode, then something like "ftp 192.168.1.1" (then enter) to start a file transfer. I want to automate this process because it will reduce errors, save time, and allow me to learn another CPP tool.

I've searched for a solution on about 5 occasions but I don't find anything. Any help is very much appreciated! Please, I don't want to abandon CPP for something easier.

Edit: The program is a text editor that is used with AIX. The text-to-be-inserted has minor changes each week.

Comment: Are you talking about a text editor? You should consider more powerful text editors such as vim/emacs... but in case you're very determined, you'd have to tell us what operating system you use. EDIT: I saw the tag too late. I'll write up an example.

Comment: What have you tried?  "send keys to window" in Google turns up dozens of references, tutorials etc..  This site is for helping you over specific hurdles when you get stuck, not for doing all your research for you.  (FYI /- Windows is a very poor environment in which to be doing this, as effectively you can't use the computer yourself while your program is simulating user input actions).

Comment: Is the input the same every time? Is it a GUI program or a console one? In the latter case, consider putting all input into a text file and executing `myprogram.exe <input.txt`.

Comment: Probably [`WM_SETTEXT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632644(v=vs.85).aspx). And then sending a message saying you pressed enter or pressed a button or something. Of course if it's a console program, the above redirection solution is a definite superior alternative. If the application is open to accessibility, that's also good.

Comment: What is the tool in question? If it's something like PuTTY or CMD.exe, you can just paste the lines of commands in and it will execute them all. If it's a program that runs on the CLI, you can just pipe in the commands like Seva Alekseyev suggested.

Comment: Depending on the situation, AutoHotKey could also come in very handy here. I mean it advertises Windows automation.

Comment: @user2899162, Yes it is. Unfortunately I don't choose the text editor.


TonyD, I tried every combination of "insert" "text" "windows" that I could think of. I'm going to be interacting with this program. My end goal is to have a box for text input that will allow me to edit the output text, and a button to execute each line of text.


SevaAlekseyev, The program I'm inputting text to is like a terminal / text editor. Unfortunately there are minor changes each week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that I'm just writing this up for fun, and it isn't necessarily the proper way to go about doing things. I'm assuming you're interacting with a GUI that you do not have any control over.

Let's say I wanted to write the characters `unix` every time I hit `ALT+SHIFT+b`. Since you're on windows, we'll toy around with the windows API. So you should `#include <windows.h>`

Now, let's register our hotkey, and make a MSG that can... accept messages.

```
RegisterHotKey(NULL, 1, MOD_ALT | MOD_SHIFT, 66)
MSG msg = {0};
```

Let's check if it's pressed, and if it is, let's call a function.

```
while(GetMessage(&msg,NULL,0,0)!=0){
    if(msg.message==WM_HOTKEY)
        myFunc();
}
```

Now what does `myFunc();` do?

```
myFunc(){
    HWND handle = GetActiveWindow();
    SendMessage(handle,WM_SETTEXT, NULL, (LPARAM)_T("unix"));
}
```

And there you have it. Maybe. I don't remember the ins and outs of the windows API, **and I personally have not tried this at all myself.**

But this should be enough to get you going, and show you what to google.

Comment: This is really helpful already. But, nothing is happening when I press shift + alt + b. I can see how most it might work except for the SendMessage() command.

Comment: Hey I hope you get to see this. I finished my program with your help.

http://i.imgur.com/C1v8Tv0.png

Comment: Congrats! I'm glad I could help. Hope your program is useful! :)